# Launcher position fixed to left

Tags: unity, launcher

Whenever I try to set the launcher position to bottom, nothing happens. In both dconf editor and the terminal I have set the launcher-position as "Bottom" with no results.
In terminal this is the command I ran:

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom`

If it helps here is a list of installed applications:

- Activity Log Manager
- anbox
- Audacity
- Autokey
- Calendar
- Cheese
- Chromium
- Discord
- Document Viewer
- Deja Dup Backup Tool
- File Roller
- Freecad
- GIMP
- GNOME Calculator
- Gnome Disks
- GNOME Logs
- GNOME Power Statistics
- GNOME-3-26-1604
- GTK Common Themes
- IBUS Preferences
- Input method
- Instagraph
- Kdenlive
- LibreOffice-
  Calc,
  Draw,
  Impress,
  Math,
  Writer,
- Money Manager EX
- Photo Lens for Unity
- Print Settings
- PulseAudio Volume Control
- Remmina
- Rythmbox
- Seahorse
- Shotwell Simple Scan
- Startup Applications
- Startup Disk Center
- Steam (linux)
- Thunderbird Email
- To Do
- Transmission
- Unity Control Center
- Videos
- Vim
- Wine-
  Dungeons & Dragons Online

Plus all or most of the System Applications.

I have also restarted multiple times.
Help with this would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same with Unity tweak tool?

Comment: I am running 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I have already tried with Unity tweak tool.

Comment: Have you installed Unity? Since 18.04 come with GNOME.

Comment: I have installed Unity and it's working well now.

Answer (score 0):

If the launcher is not moving even after using terminal, Unity Tweak Tool and dconf editor:

1. **Make sure you correctly utilized the application.**

for terminal: make sure you ran `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom` and then rebooted.

for dconf Editor:go to com>canonical>unity>launcher>launcher-position and set custom value to "Bottom".

for Unity Tweak Tool: go to launcher>appearance and select Position: Bottom

*If nothing has worked so far continue:*

2. **Install Unity**

If nothing the above hasn't worked it is likely that Unity Launcher is not installed.

To install Unity:

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop` and select OK
2. Under "configuring lightdm" navigate to lightdm and select it.
3. Wait for it to finish and then restart. From here click the Ubuntu Symbol and make sure it is set to use Unity.
4. Log-in and verify that step the first step has been completed (Make sure you correctly utilized the application)

*Now, Unity should be installed and the launch bar moved.*

For more detail in installing Unity see this article:

https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/

**If you do not want to install unity:**

Go to settings>dock>position on screen and set it to bottom.